# Vendor.bundle.js is missing in angular 6?

Tags: angular-cli

Build using ng build it will generate following. And size of vendor.js is too high.

[image: VendorJs]

Comment: Use `ng build --prod` it would apply a lot of optimizations to your code and will make the bundle size smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng build --prod --vendor-chunk=true
```

use it to bundle vendor.bundle.js separately